# serverless appsync deployment issue

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

while creating Appsync using Serverless I am getting the duplication for each deployment .And every appsync it was not creating the data source ,schema and resolver.

```
plugins:
  - serverless-appsync-plugin
custom:
  appSync:
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-projectDetails
    schema: schema.graphql
    authenticationType: AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS
     userPoolConfig:
       awsRegion: ap-south-1
       defaultAction: ALLOW
       userPoolId: 
        Ref: userCognito
   mappingTemplatesLocation:
   mappingTemplates:
    - type: Query
      field: getMerchantDetails
      dataSource: merchantDetails
      request: "mutation/request/merchantDetails.vtl"
      response: "mutation/response/merchantDetails.vtl"
    - type: Mutation
      field: createMerchantDetails
      dataSource: MerchantDetails
      request: "mutation/request/createMerchantDetails.vtl"
      response: "mutation/response/createMe rchantDetails.vtl"
  dataSources:
    - type: AMAZON_DYNAMODB
      name: merchantDetails
      config:
        tableName: ${self:provider.stage}-projectDetails
```

Comment: HI! welcome to SO, this is not a question. Please add some more details about what you're doing, what you've tried, and what you expect to occur. That way someone can better assist you. Good luck! :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Question is not clear, but i will suggest to check the indentation in your yml file.